# Inheritance in JavaScript: Calling parent's method

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

The way I implement inheritance in JavaScript is shown in the example below. I am trying to call from the child class a method of the parent class. I have seen many examples online, that add the parent method to the prototype, and the use the call or apply function (but my implementation is not doing that). Is there a way to make this type of call?

```
function classM() //parent class
{
    this.myName = function()
    {
        console.log('parent');
    }
}

function classEM ()
{
    classM.call(this);

    this.myName = function()
    {
        console.log('child');
        //HOW DO I CALL myName() of the parent class?
    }

}


classEM.prototype = Object.create(classM.prototype);
classEM.prototype.constructor = classEM;




var rm = new classEM();
rm.myName(); //should print child and then parent
```

Comment: You can't change the constructor like that, fail!

Comment: You're not using prototypal inheritance on `classM`, so `Object.create(classM.prototype)` returns an object with no `myName` method. When you do `classM.call(this)`, the object gets the method, but then you overwrite it, so no, you can't call it.

Comment: @adeno What do you mean? Please be more specific

Comment: @cookiemonster I understand that, but is there a way to fix it?

Comment: If you want to call both `myName` methods, why not create a new instance of `classM` inside `classEM` and call the darn method ?

Comment: Given that you don't want to use prototypal inheritance on `classM`, no, there's no way to fix it since a property on an object can't reference two different values at the same time. If you put the `myName` method on `classM.prototype`, then you could do `classM.prototype.myName.call(this)`. Overall, I don't know why you're setting the `.prototype` of the constructor, but not using prototypal inheritance.

Comment: @adeno Because I am trying to learn and understand how to call a parent method that I have overridden in the child class

Comment: Without inheritance, you don't really have a parent with a child class, so any solution will be a hack, and you could just as well create an instance of the "parent" inside the "child" and call the method directly, and if you want it to first log `child` and then `parent` when calling `myName` once, overwriting the function isn't going to work, as then it would no longer log `child` etc.

Comment: The following answer explains in detail how constructor functions and prototype can be used for inheritance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `this.myName = ...` in `classEM`, you are replacing the old `myName` function created by the parent with the one in `classEM`. So only one function exists now. Instead, you can add the `myName` function in the `classM`'s prototype and inherit from it.

So the program becomes like this

```
function classM() {}

// Add myName to the parent
classM.prototype.myName = function() {
    console.log('parent');
}

function classEM() {
    this.myName = function() {
        // Get the parent prototype object and invoke the myName in it.
        Object.getPrototypeOf(this).myName();
        console.log('child');
    }
}

classEM.prototype = Object.create(classM.prototype);
classEM.prototype.constructor = classEM;

var rm = new classEM();
rm.myName();
```

**Output**

```
parent
child
```

Comment: I came up with the same solution, but instead of the Object.getPrototypeOf(this).myName(); I call  classM.prototype.myName.call(this);. Do you know if there is a difference between your way and this one?

Comment: @FranXh Well, my approach will have the flexibility with the `this`. We can dynamically change the `this` object :-)

Comment: I see. The reason I was asking is mostly because of the "this" and "that" usage in JavaScript. I use "that" inside functions

Comment: @FranXh Normally, when we define inner functions, if they need to retain the `this` of the outer function, we store it in a conventional variable `that` as `var that = this`. Apart from that we don't have to worry much about `that`